# Arrow not showing consistently in tikz \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, circles, tikz-graphdrawing, edge

I would like to have a figure, where every edge has an arrow. When I `\draw` edges with tikz, something strange happens: The "same" code yields different results.

**Code**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,
                   auto,node distance=3.5cm, thick,node/.style={circle,draw}]
        \node[node] (L) {Lousy};
        \node[node] (R) [right of=L] {Right};

        \draw
            (L) to [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A} (L)
            (R) to [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A, B, C} (R)
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Result**

[image]

**Observation**

While on the left side there is no arrow, on the right side there is an arrow. The function call drawing the edge seems to be the same, though.

I am rather new to tikz, and I have no idea how to fix this. Any insight on why this happens and how to fix it, would be very appreciated.

Comment: It is because the arrow is only drawn at the END of the path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two `\draw` commands are needed. With `->` among the options in the surrounding `tikzpicture`:

```
    \draw
        (L) to [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A} (L)
        ;
    \draw
        (R) to [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A, B, C} (R)
        ;
```

Details are explained in the [pgf/TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), "16.2 Where and When Arrow Tips Are Placed".

Answer (score 3):

You should use two separate paths, one for each arrow:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,
                   auto,node distance=3.5cm, thick,node/.style={circle,draw}]
        \node[node] (L) {Lousy};
        \node[node] (R) [right of=L] {Right};

        \draw
            (L) to [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A} (L);
        \draw
            (R) to [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A, B, C} (R);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you want to keep it in one path, use the `edge` operation instead of `to`:

```
\draw
    (L) edge [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A} (L)
    (R) edge [in=300, out=240, looseness=3] node [below] {A, B, C} (R)
    ;
```